# Parse string array and and pick specfic node value

Tags: java, json, gson

this is coming as string i have to extract "message" from this using minimum line

already tried GSON, Object mapper

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "timestamp": "2019-10-17T10:45:26.276+0000",
      "message": "This is an error",
      "debugMessage": "not working"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my code that i have tried so far

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser(); 
JsonElement element = parser.parse(response); 
JsonObject jsonObj = element.getAsJsonObject(); 
String errCode = jsonObj.get("errors").getAsString();
```

Comment: show the code that you tried

Comment: JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
  JsonElement element = parser.parse(response);
  JsonObject jsonObj = element.getAsJsonObject();
  String errCode = jsonObj.get("errors").getAsString();

Answer (score 0):

In the above `JSON` example `errors` is a `JsonArray`

```
JsonArray errCode = jsonObj.get("errors").getAsJsonArray();
```

**Which is :**

```
"errors": [
  {
  "timestamp": "2019-10-17T10:45:26.276+0000",
  "message": "This is an error",
  "debugMessage": "not working"
  }
]
```

And then from `JsonArray` you need to get the fist `JsonObject` which is at index `0`

```
JsonObject innerObj = errCode.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
```

**Which is :**

```
{
  "timestamp": "2019-10-17T10:45:26.276+0000",
  "message": "This is an error",
  "debugMessage": "not working"
}
```

Now get the `message` from `JsonObject`

```
String msg = innerObj.get("message").getAsString();
```

**Which is :**

```
"message": "This is an error"
```

Comment: Worked with small chnages:  JsonElement msg = innerObj.get("message");